# How to Totally Suppress Perl "no user" Errors

Tags: shell, find

Okay, so I have a fairly simple script with a background `find` command that runs commands on the results. However, the script is sometimes running at shutdown, and doesn't always get to close cleanly (my trap doesn't always trigger, an annoying OS X quirk for `launchd` jobs).

Anyway, when this happens the script generates a bunch of errors in its log file for `"perl: no user 501"`, presumably because the script's user is being logged out.

This isn't really a problem as it doesn't break anything, and the script won't attempt to do anything, but I can't seem to stop these errors from being logged, as redirecting stderr doesn't seem to help.

Here's a heavily trimmed down version of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'rm -f /tmp/files_buffer 2>/dev/null' INT HUP TERM EXIT
mkfifo /tmp/files_buffer

filter() { [[ "$1" < "$2" ]] || return $?; }
export -f 'filter'
{ find "$1" -type f -iname '*.foo' -exec bash -c 'filter \"$@\"' -- {} "$2" \; -print0 >/tmp/files_buffer 2>/dev/null; printf '\0'; } &

while read path; do
    [ -z "$path" ] && break

    read inode modified <<<$(stat -f '%i %m' "$path" 2>/dev/null)
    checksum=$(shasum -a 256 "$path" 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}')

    echo "$path ($inode, $modified) = $checksum"
done </tmp/files_buffer
```

As you can see I've redirected stderr from all the repeated commands, yet the error is still generated from somewhere. Nice and confusing too since it's a perl error but I'm not calling perl directly anywhere ;)

Is there some possible source for the error that I've missed, and any way that I can suppress it?

Comment: the `/usr/bin/shasum` is an perl script.

Comment: Ah! I think my code snippet doesn't tell the whole picture; in my snippet I've correctly redirect stderr to `/dev/null` but in my actual script I haven't (thanks to a typo), so it was still outputting the error. I've fixed the redirect and the error is now being suppressed correctly, thanks!